# Regex to exclude multiple IPs

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to create one filter to exclude different IP ranges in google analytics view. i.e. all of below. Do i just put them each in () use | in between them?

```
^212\.153\.12\.(6[5-9]|[7-8][0-9]|9[0-4])$
^203\.39\.12\.(2(2[5-9]|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$
^208\.48\.53\.(1(29|[3-8][0-9]|90))$|^200\.142\.99\.(2(49|5[0-4]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the way if there's only one filter regex string available. Use single `^` and `$` at the start and at the end of the whole regex string.

`^first|second|third|fourth$`

Also there're excessive parenthesis when you construct 3 digit numbers (only if you're not trying to do complex group capture):

`(2(2[5-9]|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-4])) ---> 2(2[5-9]|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-4])`.

End regex can be like: `^212\.153\.12\.(6[5-9]|[7-8][0-9]|9[0-4])|203\.39\.12\.2(2[5-9]|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-4])|208\.48\.53\.1(29|[3-8][0-9]|90)|200\.142\.99\.2(49|5[0-4])$`